# Apache spark accuracy differs for every run and has run time exceptions some times

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest, logistic-regression

This is the [Github link](http://github.com/Arvin6/Heartfailureprediction/tree/review2),
If someone wants to reproduce it. For some reason this program returns different values every time I run it. This is actually a Github project that I wanted to check out. There was one part of data set missing but I managed to run it without it. The problem is, it runs properly at times but returns different accuracy each time. Also sometimes, I get Assertion exception and Unsupported operation exception. Do anyone have any idea as to why it happens?

I was running bagging with Logistic regression and Random forest on seperate Spark MLlib pipelines. It runs fine but returns different accuracy levels and confusion matrix everytime. Sometimes it throws an exception and the stacktrace is given below.

```
    Dataset size: 2
    B- Sample size: 5                                                                                     
    17/04/28 13:19:43 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 0.7559                                                       
    17/04/28 13:19:43 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.143776 (rel: 0.793) 0.160762
    17/04/28 13:19:43 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000
    17/04/28 13:19:43 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.127285 (rel: 0.115) 0.0815899
    17/04/28 13:19:44 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000
    17/04/28 13:19:44 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.120321 (rel: 0.0547) 0.0207179
    17/04/28 13:19:45 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000                                                        
    17/04/28 13:19:45 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.119759 (rel: 0.00467) 0.00553480
    17/04/28 13:19:46 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000                                                        
    17/04/28 13:19:46 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.119721 (rel: 0.000315) 0.00214368
    17/04/28 13:19:46 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000
    17/04/28 13:19:46 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.119716 (rel: 3.85e-05) 0.000959314
    17/04/28 13:19:47 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000
    17/04/28 13:19:47 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.119715 (rel: 9.22e-06) 0.000185495
    17/04/28 13:19:47 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000
    17/04/28 13:19:47 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.119715 (rel: 4.08e-07) 2.80789e-05
    17/04/28 13:19:48 INFO LBFGS: Step Size: 1.000
    17/04/28 13:19:48 INFO LBFGS: Val and Grad Norm: 0.119715 (rel: 1.01e-08) 1.58237e-06
    Dataset size: 2
    B- Sample size: 0                                                                                     
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1191)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.BaggedLogisticRegression$$anonfun$train$1.apply(BaggedLogisticRegression.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.BaggedLogisticRegression$$anonfun$train$1.apply(BaggedLogisticRegression.scala:99)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.BaggedLogisticRegression.train(BaggedLogisticRegression.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.BaggedLogisticRegression.train(BaggedLogisticRegression.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.ml.impl.estimator.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.ml.impl.estimator.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:114)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.IterableViewLike$Transformed$class.foreach(IterableViewLike.scala:42)
at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$AbstractTransformed.foreach(SeqViewLike.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(Estimator.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(Estimator.scala:68)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator.fit(Estimator.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(CrossValidator.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(CrossValidator.scala:105)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator.fit(CrossValidator.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator.fit(CrossValidator.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator.fit(Estimator.scala:44)
at com.arvind.majorproject.CrossValidation.CrossValidation$.crossValidate(CrossValidation.scala:124)
at com.arvind.majorproject.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:140)
at com.arvind.majorproject.main.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
at   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Run ERROR: Aborting.
```

Comment: Please can you provide a bit more information. If you're more concerned with the exceptions, details of your cluster, as well as stack traces and the code that seems to be causing the exceptions. If you're more concerned with variation in accuracy, please can you provide examples of accuracy variation? I'd argue that you have two separate questions that would require different skillsets to solve, so you might do better asking two separate questions.

Comment: Updated with the stacktrace. Please check.